# How should I effectively store mass numerical data in Java? Please critique my solution

Tags: java, data-structures

I am a software intern designing a program which parses data files outputted by an industrial simulator in order to do calculations on them.

The basic structure of the files is like this:

Property1

Timestep 1
0.000 3.141 5.131 etc...

Timestep 2
3.323 0.000 etc...

etc...

The data needs to be collected in some sort of data structure in order to allow for efficient calculations. There can be several million data points, though many are the same value.

My solution (nested HashMaps):

The main object, DataContainer has a HashMap which contains property names as keys. These keys are associated with their own HashMaps that contain timestep numbers as keys. These keys are associated with their own HashMaps that contain data values as keys that are paired with the number of times that value occurs within the timestep.

Quick Illustration:

DataContainer
   properties:

```
  property 1 : 
               time 1 - 0.000, 4 | 3.313, 10 etc...
               time 2
```

Looking forward to people's input.

Comment: What types of calculations do you want to do?

Comment: simple stuff, like finding out the number of cells within a certain range of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in efficiency, you would be better off creating custom classes with attributes / getters / setters for the properties.

HashMaps containing HashMaps etc:

- take more space,
- are slower,
- are more tricky to use ... especially if you want to iterate the elements in a predictable order, and
- negate the benefit of Java's intrinsic compile time type safety.

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

```
class DataContainer{
   TreeMap timestamp<String, SortedList<Integer>>;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for two arrays of the same length like `double[] value; int[] count;`. This surely takes much less space than a `Map.Entry` filled with boxed values. I'd make a simple class around them, and put it into your Map.